# What will be the output of the following C program

Tags: c, pointers, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()

{
  char *p;
  p="%d\n";
  p++;
  p++;
  printf(p-2, 400);
  return 0;
}
```

When I am running above code, I am getting output 400. But why 400?

Comment: What else would you expect to get, and why?

Comment: Actually i was not aware of syntax of printf() function more deeply . So I am not understand whats happening in my code.

Answer (score 2):

The `p` is assigned the formatting string first. Then it's decrement by 1 two times. Finally its value minus two is passed to the printf with additional parameter 400.

Subtracting 2 from latest value of `p` moves it back to the original formatting string. And therefore printf prints value 400.

Answer (score 1):

`printf()`'s first parameter is a format string.  The variable `p` is a pointer to a character array which is also how strings are represented.

When p is assigned a string `"%d\n"` it says format an integer to print its value and then print the carriage return character.

Since `p` is a char pointer `p++` means move the pointer forward 1 character. This is done twice to move `p` forward 2 characters so it points to the beginning of the carriage return character. `p-2` says do pointer math to give a `char*` 2 characters in front of where `p` points.

This is the beginning of the `%d` carriage return string. This becomes the format string and the second parameter 400 replaces the `%d` and prints itself followed by the carriage return.

Answer (score 0):

You declared a pointer to a string and assigned it the value `"%d\n"`. This pointer holds an address in memory.

For example, lets say it points to address 6 when you add two to it (which you shouldn't do you you always have to know where your pointers are pointing) you change the address to 8.

Now when you do `printf` you're replacing it with the current value of the address `p` points to (8) minus 2 which is 6.